# How to change the visibility of a TextField (native library), i.e. make it invisible, in Corona SDK

Tags: lua, coronasdk

Is it possible to make a `TextField` (for the Corona SDK `native` library) invisible? If so, then how?  The `isVisible` property does not seem to work.

For example, if I create a `TextField` instance like this:

```
local textIngrediente1 = native.newTextField(...)
```

when I try to make it invisible by setting the `isVisible` property like so:

```
textIngredient1.isVisible = false
```

it has no effect on the visibility of the `TextField`.

Comment: what you have tried?

Comment: the property siVisibel, but it only work for display:Objects

Comment: oh, include you code in your question by editing. Thanks.

Comment: local text= native.newTextField( ... ) ; 
text.isVisible=false ; 
I'm trying something like this, but it don't work

Comment: why are you still commenting? Add them having [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33004317/edit) your question.

Comment: "siVisibel" Did you try [`isVisible`](https://docs.coronalabs.com/daily/api/type/DisplayObject/isVisible.html)?

Comment: Yes i did this, but it dont work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

native.newTextField() does honor the .isVisible property. I just tested it. You likely have an error if you copy and pasted your code:

```
--local textIngrediente1 = native.newTextField(...)
-- textIngredient1.isVisible = false
```

In one you use textIngredient**e**1
In the other you use textIngredient1 (no extra e)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the isVisible, and alpha properties except for display objects..
But you can set your textField off the screen and then change the x,y coordinates when you need to show the textField..

```
local text= native.newTextField( ... )
text.x = -100
text.y = -100
```

then when you need to use or show the textField object

```
text.x = 100
text.y = 100
```

I think this will do the trick

Answer (score 0):

According to the Corona documentation, [`TextField`](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/type/TextField/index.html) objects inherit properties from [`NativeDisplayObjects`](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/type/NativeDisplayObject/index.html) which inherit properties from [`DisplayObjects`](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/type/DisplayObject/index.html), including the [`isVisible` property](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/type/DisplayObject/isVisible.html), so (as long as there are no typos ;-) ) this **will** control the visibility of the `TextField`.